# Einstein Chat Bot timeout

Tags: session, einstein-chatbot

I am working on a guided chatbot integrated into a public website. For some reason the bot is not getting timed out in 30 minutes which I understand should be the default behaviour.

Instead the chat window stays active for over 2 hours. The chat duration is sometimes even lasting upto 17000 seconds ≈ 5 hours.

The Idle Connection Timeout Duration under "Chat Setup Flow" chat deployment is also kept at 1800 seconds.

- While I understand that for each chat button there is an explicit
  timeout setting, hence,do I need to actually put the timeout limit at
  button level?
- Is the Idle Connection timeout duration under chat deployment not
  relevant for chatbots?